# Removing rowcolors after long table

Tags: tables, color, longtable, rowcolor

I am trying to have a long table in which every other data entry row is in gray. This I get easily by implementing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!30}{white}
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{My Long table}
  \\ \hline   
\rowcolor{white} first & second & third \\\hline
\endfirsthead
\rowcolor{white}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{...continued from last page}} 
\\ \hline
 \rowcolor{white} first & second & third \\
\endhead
\endfoot 
\endlastfoot
James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\ James&Jana&Julia \\
\end{longtable}
```

The problem is once I am done with this long table, every other table which I introduce afterward still keeps this feature, I can reset the row colors of course, but if I want to have a table in which every other column is colored, then it gets problematic. I know that it's mentioned in the documentation of `xcolor` package that it's not compatible with `longtable`, but is there any way to circumvent this? and if not is there any other easy way to color up the rows of my long table?

Comment: Put `\rowcolors{...}\begin{longtable} ... \end{longtable}` in a group. B.t.w.., it seems that what does not work with longtable is the `optional` argument  of`\rowcolors`, as I understand it.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Done, milady!

Comment: You're welcome, la Sua Eccellenza! ;o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to put the table in a group:

```
\bgroup
\rowcolors{2}{gray!30}{white}
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
    .............
    .............
    .............
\end{longtable}
\egroup
```

Comment: i took liberty and add to your example line `\rowcolors{2}{gray!30}{white}`, which is to my opinion missed.

Comment: @Zarko: Thanks! I forgot to check the post (as often). As I had tested whether it did work by adding a second copy of the long table, I guess I pasted the second version, without \rowcolors…